How do I code an exit strategy in TradingView pine that exits pyramiding trades individually?
I am trying to write code that will close each opened trade at the close of the first bar in which that close would produce a profitable result for that particular trade. Closing on the same bar as the one that initiated the trade is not allowed, but it shouldn't be possible since the entry is at the close of the bar. I'm enabling pyramiding, so it needs to judge each lot as its own trade for the purposes of exiting, not lump them together and close the whole position.  If this exit system is working the way it should, it should be impossible for any closed trade to be a loss.  Only wins can close.  If it's not profitable yet, the trade should stay open until it is.
I'm terrible at coding so if you answer, speak to me like I'm an idiot because as far as coding goes, I am.  Thanks for any help anyone can give!
Question answered by @vitruvius - a true hero.

In order for this to work, you need to give unique ids to your trades.
strategy.entry(id, direction, qty, limit, stop, oca_name, oca_type, comment, alert_message, disable_alert) → void


id (series string) The identifier of the order, which corresponds to
an entry ID in the strategy's trades after the order fills. If the
strategy opens a new position after filling the order, the order's ID
becomes the strategy.position_entry_name value. Strategy commands can
reference the order ID to cancel or modify pending orders and generate
exit orders for specific open trades. The Strategy Tester and the
chart display the order ID unless the command specifies a comment
value.

One way to do this is to use a counter system. For example, L-1, L-2, L-3 ... for long trades.
Then, when you place your close order, you will refer to this entry id.
strategy.close(id, comment, qty, qty_percent, alert_message, immediately, disable_alert) → void


id (series string) The entry identifier of the open trades to close.

This is the basic idea. The implemenatation is up to you. Somehow you need to know the trade id and the profit.
You can use the built-in variables to loop over the open trades, get the profit and trade id. Then you can call strategy.close() if that specific trade is in profit.
One important note is, you need to set close_entries_rule="ANY". Otherwise, earliest exit order must close the earliest entry order.
Here is an example for you:
//@version=6
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, pyramiding=10, process_orders_on_close=true, close_entries_rule="ANY")

var long_cnt = 1

long_entry_cond = (bar_index % 3) == 0                      // Enter a new trade every third bar

if (long_entry_cond)
    long_id = "L-" + str.tostring(long_cnt)                 // Create the entry id
    strategy.entry(long_id, strategy.long)

if (strategy.position_size > strategy.position_size[1])     // New trade
    long_cnt := long_cnt + 1

for i = 0 to strategy.opentrades - 1
    trade_id = strategy.opentrades.entry_id(i)
    profit = strategy.opentrades.profit(i)

    if (profit > 0)                                      // In profit
        strategy.close(trade_id, comment="C-" + trade_id)
        s = "Trade: " + trade_id + "\nProfit: " + str.tostring(profit, format.price)
        label.new(bar_index, high, s)



I am being absolutely sincere when I say this - I literally have tears welling up in my eyes as I type this.  I have been fighting this fight for longer than I can even remember.  Endless hours of frustration and even more endless hours of having to backtest manually tick by tick.  Hundreds of thousands of ticks worth of manual backtesting so far and who knows how many more would have followed...and you just ended it with your extraordinary act of kindness.  I don't even have the words to thank appropriately for your help.  Thank you SO much. I am truly overwhelmed with gratitude.
